# 3 Columns centered css grid has 1px margin on the right

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm doing some testing with the css-grid spec and am encountering an issue on my first test. I wanted to create a centered grid with 3 columns and have divs inside the grid fill the width of the columns. This works but i was not expecting the 1px margin on the right see:

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.cell {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell">a</div>
    <div class="cell">b</div>
    <div class="cell">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect this has to do with a percentage rounding issue. If you scale the browser you see that the margin sometimes disappears.

I know i can fix this with flexbox and let the cell grow, but i'd rather know how to handle this with css-grid.

Answer (score 0):

It's a math and could not be fixed. For example, if you divide 100 to 3, you will get something like 33.33333333333333..........

By the way, you could use

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
```

Instead of

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr, 1fr, 1fr;
```

Comment: Thanks i'm aware of the rounding issues, but you would imagine that, considering the grid "lines" that the last line would be right on the edge of the parent container, and thus filling right to the edge. Besides that, firefox also renders it perfectly.

Comment: You ask too much intelligence from CSS. If you have 400pixels div, and you ask to divide it to 3 pixel-perfect fractions, it's not possible. If you need it, you have to reduce the width of parent div (as Michael suggested).

Comment: Yeah, someone pointed me to this article also which points out my specific issue. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/09/css-grid-gotchas-stumbling-blocks/#im-having-trouble-with-my-percentages